# C# Windows Phone 8.1 GetOutputStreamAsync(...) blocking after first use

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, udp, async-await, broadcast

i'm currently trying to create a very basic test app which should:

1) Broadcast "sometext" on port "1234"
2) Wait a second for answers
3) Return all answers

While the solution posted below works fine for the first time, every subsequent call blocks forever at:
*stream = await socket.GetOutputStreamAsync(...)*

Till now i tried every possible way of cleaning up (since thats where i suppose the failure), even wrapping everything in *using(...)* statements.

The problem occurs with the emulator as well as a hardware device using Windows Phone 8.1

---

Thanks in advance!

---

The code to start the "discovery":

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PluginUDP pudp = new PluginUDP();
    var task = pudp.scan("asf");
    task.Wait();
    foreach (string s in task.Result)
        output.Text += s + "\r\n";            
}
```

---

The code for the "discovery" itself:

```cs
using System;
using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

using namespace whatever
{
    public class PluginUDP
    {
        private static readonly HostName BroadcastAddress = new HostName("255.255.255.255");
        private static readonly string BroadcastPort = "1234";
        private static readonly byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("00wlan-ping00");

        ConcurrentBag<string> receivers;        

        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string[]> scan(string options)
        {
            receivers = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
            receivers.Add("ok");

            DatagramSocket socket = null;
            IOutputStream stream = null;
            DataWriter writer = null;

            try
            {
                socket = new DatagramSocket();                
                socket.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;

                await socket.BindServiceNameAsync("");

                stream = await socket.GetOutputStreamAsync(BroadcastAddress, BroadcastPort);
                writer = new DataWriter(stream);               

                writer.WriteBytes(data);
                await writer.StoreAsync();

                Task.Delay(1000).Wait();                
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                receivers.Add(exception.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (writer != null)
                {
                    writer.DetachStream();
                    writer.Dispose();
                }

                if(stream != null)
                    stream.Dispose();

                if(socket != null)
                    socket.Dispose();
            }

            return receivers.ToArray(); ;
        }

        private async void MessageReceived(DatagramSocket socket, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = args.GetDataStream();
                var resultStream = result.AsStreamForRead(1024);

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(resultStream))
                {
                    var text = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    if (text.Contains("pong"))
                    {
                        receivers.Add(args.RemoteAddress.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                receivers.Add("ERRCV");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem starts here:

```
task.Wait();
```

[*You're blocking on async code*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), which leads you to a **deadlock.**

You want:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PluginUDP pudp = new PluginUDP();
    string[] result = await pudp.scan("asf");
    foreach (string s in result)
        output.Text += s + "\r\n";            
}
```

You also want to do:

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
```

Instead of:

```
Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
```